# true or false on click or onchange syntax reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i am not able to get reverse of **todo.complete**
like if i use **todo.complete = !todo.complete** it donot work. but if use **todo.complete = true*(or false)*** it works. i want to make it reverse of true or false but it happens only true or only false.

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import TodoItems from "./todoitems";
    import TodoData from "./tododata";
    import React from "react";
    
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          Todos: TodoData
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
      handleChange(id) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const updatedTodos = prevState.Todos.map((todo) => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
              **todo.complete = true;**
            }
            return todo;
          });
          return {
            Todos: updatedTodos
          };
        });
      }
      render() {
        const TodoItem = TodoData.map((item) => (
          <TodoItems item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} key={item.id} />
        ));
    
        return <div>{TodoItem}</div>;
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Which content has `complete`? If not boolean try using `todo.complete = Boolean(!todo.complete)`

Comment: this workes.thanks